# Why mutex isn't locked

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4

I have problem with mutex, can't figure out why piece of code between lock and unlock runs at the same time in all threads.
Here is my thread class:

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
    load_message_input = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, id, window):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.window = window

    def run(self):
        print "Thread %d is started" % self.id
        self.get_captcha_value()
        print "Thread %d is finishing" % self.id

    def get_captcha_value(self):
        MyThread.mutex.lock()
        print "Thread %d locks mutex" % self.id
        self.load_message_input.connect(self.window.show_input)
        self.load_message_input.emit()
        self.window.got_message.connect(self.print_message)
        self.window.input_finished.wait(self.mutex)
        print "Thread %d unlocks mutex" % self.id
        MyThread.mutex.unlock()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QString")
    def print_message(self, msg):
        print "Thread %d: %s" % (self.id, msg)
```

Here's how i describe window:

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    got_message = QtCore.pyqtSignal("QString")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.last_message = None

        self.setModal(True)
        self.message_label = QtGui.QLabel(u"Message")
        self.message_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.dialog_buttons = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.dialog_buttons.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.dialog_buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.message_label)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.message_input)
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.dialog_buttons)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.input_finished = QtCore.QWaitCondition()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_input(self):
        print "showing input"
        self.show()
        self.setModal(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_accepted(self):
        print "emit: ", self.message_input.text()
        self.got_message.emit(self.message_input.text())
        self.input_finished.wakeAll()
```

And here's main thread:

```
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = test_qdialog.MyDialog()
threads = []

for i in range(5):
    thread = MyThread(i, window)
    if not thread.isRunning():
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output looks like this:

```
Thread 0 is startedThread 1 is startedThread 4 is started


Thread 0 locks mutexThread 3 is started
Thread 2 is started

Thread 2 locks mutex
Thread 3 locks mutex
Thread 1 locks mutex
Thread 4 locks mutex
showing input
showing input
showing input
showing input
showing input
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Yoann for his suggestions.
Here's how MyThread class code looks like now:

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
    load_message_input = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, id, window):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.window = window
        # self.mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
        self.load_message_input.connect(self.window.show_input)

    def run(self):
        print "Thread %d is started" % self.id
        self.get_captcha_value()
        print "Thread %d is finishing" % self.id

    def get_captcha_value(self):
        MyThread.mutex.lock()
        print "Thread %d locks mutex" % self.id
        self.load_message_input.emit()
        mutex2 = QtCore.QMutex()
        mutex2.lock()
        self.window.got_message.connect(self.print_message)
        self.window.input_finished.wait(mutex2)
        mutex2.unlock()
        self.window.got_message.disconnect(self.print_message)
        print "Thread %d unlocks mutex" % self.id
        MyThread.mutex.unlock()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QString")
    def print_message(self, msg):
        print "Thread %d: %s" % (self.id, msg)
```

Now I get this this exception after first thread is finished:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/script/qdialog_threads.py", line 20, in run
    self.get_captcha_value()
  File "path/to/script/qdialog_threads.py", line 34, in get_captcha_value
    MyThread.mutex.unlock()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mutex'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not flushing the buffers in your `print` calls. Also be aware that the `showing input` output is generated in the GUI thread, so it may happen any time after the mutex has been locked - including after the mutex is already unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code

**Your call to print are all mixed up**

It can easily be fixed by locking every print this way (the `with` statement is a context manager which handles acquiring and releasing of the lock):

```
# Lock declaration
CONSOLELOCK = threading.Lock()

# Then for any print
with CONSOLELOCK:
    print("Anything")
```

As Kuba Ober said, showing input output is generated in the GUI thread, so it may appear in the wrong order anyway.

**You use one mutex when you should use two**

When you call `self.window.input_finished.wait(self.mutex)`, the mutex is released, so every other thread will try to acquire it. The first to arrive will acquire it, emit `load_message` then wait for input_finished and release the mutex and so on. Eventually, every thread will have locked the mutex, emitted `load_message` and be waiting for the same condition (accepted signal of the same dialog). One solution would be to use a second mutex than you will use with your condition. `self.window.input_finished.wait(self.mutex2)`.

Besides, your `on_accepted` slot is never called and you never disconnect the `window.got_message` signal so your threads stay alive.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that `wait()` releases mutex automatically. But now I have different problem. Right after first thread is finished, whole program finishes. So I can input message one time, not five. I'll add updated code for MyThread class to question.

Comment: If the accepted slot of your Dialog is called, then it will close. Since there's no more open window, the application will automatically exit. This behaviour can be disabled by calling setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)